# Install a new version of app that not in repository and including all dependencies

Tags: dependencies, deb

The problem I want to solve is that I want to install an app from source.

When I tried to install that app, it said that it needs `valac-0.16`, but when I tried to install `valac` from terminal, it is only installing an older version, `valac-0.14`.
Then I tried to download the new version of `valac-0.16` and tried to install it, but it still shows the dependency is not satisfied.

How can I install a new version of a app that not in the repos?

Comment: I did some heavy editing of your question according to my best understanding of your problem.  If I have misstated something, and/or you can add clarifications where the question is unclear, please edit the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to install a package which somehow `Depends: valac (>= 0.16)` and it refuses to install although you downloaded and installed the `valac` upstream sources.

If you have a package which declares a dependency which cannot be satisfied, `dpkg` will refuse to install it until `dpkg` knows that the dependency is satisfied.  There are three possible fixes;

1. `dpkg --force-depends-version -i package` will make `dpkg` accept `valac` 0.14 even if `package` states that it requires >= 0.16.  More generally, `dpkg --force-help` contains various hints for how to make `dpkg` shoot itself in the foot in various interesting and sometimes useful ways.  If you are not using `dpkg` directly, there are ways to pass in these options from `apt-get`, `aptitude`, etc.
2. If `valac` has a `debian` directory, or you otherwise know how to create a package from the 0.16 sources you downloaded, just build and install a `deb` package instead.  `debuild -us -uc -rfakeroot -b` should be all you need if the pieces are there (most notably, `debian/rules`).  Alternatively, you may be able to piece together a package from `apt-get source valac` and installing the 0.16 upstream sources in the 0.14 package source tree, then rebuilding.
3. If you have a local install of a package which would satisfy the dependency, but `dpkg` doesn't know about it, you can create a dummy package and install it; then `dpkg` will be satisfied.  The [`equivs`](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-helpers.en.html) package allows you to easily create a dummy package like that.